# Converting Quaternions to the Euler Angles that is closest to another Euler Angle

Tags: continuity, rotations, quaternions

I have an euler angle representing an objects rotation. I want to rotate the object by a quaternion, while still preserving continuity in the euler angle representation. In the following example all Euler Angles are in xyz:

Source Euler Angle: `(0, 0, 310)`
Rotate by Euler Angle: `(0, 0, 60)`

I convert the angles to quaternions, perform the rotation and the continuity is lost:

After rotating Euler Angle: `(0, 0, 10)` 
Desired result: `(0, 0, 370)`

I tried to solve this by comparing and manipulating the resulting euler angles for x, y and z respectively using the following algorithm:

```
new_euler.x = repeat_working(new_euler.x - src_euler.x + 180, 360) + src_euler.x - 180
new_euler.y = ...

func repeat_working (t):
    return (t - (floor(t / 360) * 360))
```

It still produces jumping values for Y and Z when rotating around the X-Axis. When rotating around the Y-Axis the values are alternating instead of increasing continously (Rotations are performed around the Z axis, the X axis, and the Y axis, in that order).

Could someone point out my mistake, or a better alternative method of doing this? Ideally some code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but there is a topological reason that combining rotations in the Euler angle domain cannot be continuous. That's because the natural space for rotations is topologically a 3-sphere (antipodal points identified) $S^3$ where as the space of Euler angles reside in a threefold cartesian product of a circle, that is $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$. The two spaces are not homeomorphic, so no continuous bijection between them can exist. Gimbal locks are possibly the best known manifestation of this discontinuity.

Comment: 1) There is no "the" Euler angle representation, as there are gazillion many different conventions all claiming themselves as "the standard". 2) Why are you using Euler angles in the first place? If possible, avoid them and just stick to quaternions as they are infinitely better for most of computational purposes. The only natural scenario for needing Euler angles is when you need to control mechanical devices consisting of three rotating rings. Are you in that situation?

Comment: 3) Assuming that is indeed the case, what you are doing in the code is indeed forcing discontinuity. Note that you are forcing the angles to be in between 0 and 360 which I think is precisely what you want to avoid? Instead, you may need to use `angle + 360*n` for whatever `n` resulting in the value closest to the previous angle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my application users enter a axis-angle rotation for a joint, and the user in the end sees the final rotation of the joint, here eulers are more convient to understand. Then he can interpolate between two rotations, but the interpolation should be continously and supporting arbitary number of windings.

Comment: In my humble opinion, axis-angle representation is the most intuitive, while the Euler angles are the least intuitive way of representing rotations. Can you imagine what will be the final orientation if you rotate your object by 60 degrees along the x-axis and then 30 degrees along the y-axis and then 90 degrees along the z-axis? On the contrary, it is relatively trivial to imagine what will happen if you rotate your object by an arbitrary angle along an arbitrary axis.

Comment: Also you said user can interpolate between two rotations. Quaternions are the best for such purpose. Continuity is automatic if the displacement is not over 180 degrees. My personal opinion is that you should just get rid of Euler angles. But if you want to insist, I think computing `n` from the previous comment should work.